# Add a condition to skip a transformation in ADF Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF Data Flow that includes a filter as shown below:

[image]

I need to set a parameter and set a condition before filter and based on that condition it should or should not perform filter step.

For example, parameter = environment

If environment = non prod, do filter transformation

Else If environment = prod, skip filter transformation.

Is there a way to add this parameter and condition via ADF Data Flow?

**UPDATE:**

I added a parameter as follows:

[image]
I added a conditional split as follows:

[image]

This doesn't skip Filter transformation when environment = prod. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Conditional Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-conditional-split) transformation for conditional logic